# Golang interface method chaining

Tags: go, interface, method-chaining

I have an interface `Cells` with several methods

```
type Cells interface{
    Len() int
    //....
}
```

Concrete implementations of this are `StrCells`, `IntCells`, `FloatCells` and `BoolCells`, all of which have the above methods implemented.

E.g.:

```
type StrCells []string
func (sC StrCells) Len() int {return len(sC)}
//...

type IntCells []int
func (iC IntCells) Len() int {return len(iC)}
//...

//....
```

For two of the concrete types - `IntCells` and `FloatCells` - I want to implement specific functions only applicable to those types.

I create a new interface `NumCells` which embedds `Cells`

```
type NumCells interface{
    Cells
    Add(NumCells) interface{} // should return either IntCells or FloatCells 
}
```

Here is my implementation of `Add()` for IntCells:

```
func (iC IntCells) Add(nC NumCells) interface{} {
    if iC.Len() != nC.Len() {
        // do stuff
    }
    switch nC.(type) {
    case IntCells:
        res := make(IntCells, iC.Len())
        for i, v := range iC {
            res[i] = v + nC.(IntCells)[i]
        }
        return res
    case FloatCells:
        res := make(FloatCells, iC.Len())
        for i, v := range iC {
            res[i] = float64(v) + nC.(FloatCells)[i]
        }
        return res
    default:
        // to come
        return nil
    }

}
```

**Here is my question / problem**

The function works, however, I actually want the function to return `NumCells` (i.e. either IntCells or FloatCells) so I could do method chaining like this

```
a := columns.IntCells(1, 2, 4, 2)
b := columns.IntCells{2, 3, 5, 3}
c := columns.FloatCells{3.1, 2, 2.4, 3.2}
d := a.Add(b).Add(c)
```

This is not possible if `Add()` returns an `interface{}`. However, I am not able to make the function work otherwise.

Comment: It's a pretty serious code smell if your implementation of `IntCells` needs to know that `FloatCells` exists.

Comment: But to your question: Why not just make it return `NumCells` then?

Comment: Hi @Flimzy thanks for your swift response. Will edit regarding inheritance. Regarding "code smell". I am a self-taught coder just learning `go`. So any suggestions will help!

Comment: One of the reasons to use interfaces is so that your implementations _don't have to know about each other_. Any interaction between implementations should happen _through the interface_. So if your `IntCells` needs information about another type, get it through the defined interface, not by doing type assertions and building logic about other types into `IntCells`.

Comment: So you mean I should use type switch in something like `Add(nC NumCells)` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you define your `NumCells` interface this way:

```
type NumCells interface{
    Cells
    Add(NumCells) NumCells // returns either IntCells or FloatCells
}
```

You then need both `IntCells` and `FloatCells` to implement `Add` and return one of those types.

Here's a working playground, using method chaining and printing the result:

https://play.golang.org/p/W7DzcB4A3NH

As stated in the comments, when using interfaces one usually wants to make each type agnostic of the rest of the implementations and just use the interface without type switches.

One way to avoid those type switches in the implementations of `Add` might be to add another method in the `NumCells` to return a particular position as a `float64`.

```
type NumCells interface{
    Cells
    Add(NumCells) NumCells // returns either IntCells or FloatCells
    GetCell(index int) float64
}
```

So that then you can get the value without needing to assert the particular type.

Since `IntCells` cannot accommodate `float64` values, it'd still need to create a `FloatCells` to return it, if we want to avoid `IntCells` doing that we'd need to abstract the creation of the objects somehow, using a factory pattern or similar.

Comment: Thanks. This works! Although I am now struggling to understand Flimzy's comment.

Comment: @FredMaster, I updated my answer to include some more explanations regarding trying to avoid the type switches to make it more complete.

Comment: Great. Thanks! This gives me something to chew on :-)